# How to remove a certain part of a string in Dart?

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I am sure the solution is pretty simple.

I want to reduce a String by another String which is contained in the first one.

Here is my code

```
String street = "2576 Lombard St"
String houseNumber = "2576"
```

I only need a function to remove the house Number from the String "street". So the endresult should look like this:

```
String streetname = "Lombard St"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code will do what you want

```dart
    const String street = '2576 Lombard St';
    const String houseNumber = '2576';
    final String streetName = street.replaceAll(houseNumber, '').trim();
    print('Street name: $streetName'); // Street name: Lombard St
```

If you want to remove all digits

```dart
    const String street = '2576 Lombard St';
    const String houseNumber = '2576';
    final String streetName = street.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\d+'), '').trim();
    print('Street name: $streetName'); // Street name: Lombard St
```

If you only want to remove the first `houseNumber`;

```dart
    const String street = '2576 Lombard St';
    const String houseNumber = '2576';
    final String streetName = street.replaceFirst(houseNumber, '');
    print('Street name: $streetName'); // Street name: Lombard St
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.replaceAll`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) on String.

```dart
String removeHouseNumber(String street, String houseNumber) {
  return street.replaceAll(houseNumber, "").trim();
}

String street = "2576 Lombard St";

String houseNumber = "2576";
print(removeHouseNumber(street,houseNumber)); //Lombard St
```